# How do I specify which java function to use in clojure?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure you can only write

```
(.getName guild)
```

for JDA.
I want to get the name of this guild, but it's trying to cast it to Class from Java, instead. I cannot exactly type something like this either to my understanding:

```
(Guild/getName guild)
; nor this:
(Guild.getName guild)
; and at least not this:
(guild.getName)
```

Do anyone know what to do?

Comment: What is this guild object? How is it created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by simply using type hinting:

```
(let [^Guild guild (.getGuildById jda "idHere")])
```